# Validation for dynamic radio button,checkbox and text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have developed one page,which is contains several questions and answer...there are three types of answer radio button,checkbox and text area... i have to validate these dynamically created questions using javascript...

based on the question type i am getting answer options from database whether it may be a radio button  or checkbox or text area...

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" name="21" value="59"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio" name="22" value="60"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio" name="23" value="61"/>
```

like same as checkbox and text area....

//try 1

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase == 'radio' && !inputs[i].checked)
return false;
}
return true;
```

//try 2

```
var rv = document.getElementsByName("reservation_in");
var ci = -1;
for(var ikj=0; ikj < rv.length; ikj++){
if(rv[ikj].checked) {
ci = ikj; 
}
}
if (ci == -1) {
document.getElementById('err_reservation_for').innerHTML="";
document.getElementById('err_reservation_for').innerHTML=
'Please&nbsp;let&nbsp;us&nbsp;know&nbsp;
//Reservation&nbsp;for&nbsp;Inside&nbsp;or&nbsp;Patio.';
return false;
}
```

//try 3

```
var radios = document.getElementById('radio');
var formValid = false;
var i = 0;
while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
if (radios[i].checked) 
formValid = true;
i++;
}
if (!formValid)
//document.getElementById('radio_error').innerHTML="";
//document.getElementById('radio_error').innerHTML=
'Please&nbsp;select&nbsp;one&nbsp;answer.';
alert("Please select the answer");
return formValid;
```

Comment: *.... i have to validate these dynamically created questions using javascript...* Ok. Good. Can You Share More Code Which You Tried From Your End. Any Javascript Code ?

Comment: Use this for Radio button validation
http://adobe.github.io/Spry/articles/radio_overview/index.html

Comment: id should be different for all elements.

Comment: @Ajay right id should be different and name should be same for one question answer

Comment: here am getting the questions and options from table... if question is there based on the question id i am getting options in other table..so i am using while loop for this question and options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some sample code which may help you to understand more.

HTML Code:

```
   <div id="que1" class="que">
    xyz is not abc? <br />
   <div class="ans">
   <input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" id="radio1" />One
   <input type="radio" name="radioGroup1" id="radio2" />Two 
   <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check1" />Three  <br/>
   <textarea id="textarea-1"></textarea>
   </div>
    </div><br />
   <div id="que2" class="que">
       xyz is not abc? <br />
      <div class="ans">
    <input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" id="radio3" />One
    <input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" id="radio3" />Two 
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check2" />Three  <br />
    <textarea id="textarea-2"></textarea>
  </div>

  </div>
```

JS Code:

```
var questions=document.getElementsByClassName("que");
for(var i=0;i<questions.length;i++){
   var inputs=questions[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var j=0;j<inputs.length;j++){
      if(inputs[j].type=="radio"){
       alert("question ID:- "+ questions[i].id+ " radio");
      }
      if(inputs[j].type=="checkbox"){
       alert("question ID:- "+ questions[i].id+ " checkbox");
     }
   }
   var textarea=questions[i].getElementsByTagName("textarea");
   for(var k=0;k<textarea.length;k++){
      alert("question ID:- "+ questions[i].id+ " Textarea");
  }
 }
```

[Click here check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashantteli/24d4emqg/2/#&togetherjs=jV66mxHEsn)

Comment: i tried your's...i am getting questions length 5....but control is not coming inside first for loop(for (var i=0;i<questions.length;i++){  )

Comment: Can you create fiddle and share what you did exactly?

Comment: visit https://jsfiddle.net/  Login/Signup you get html, js, css ide paste you code respectively. save and share

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zbqb1jjq/1/      each question is in each table...so 5 questions 5 table

Comment: Remove class question from "td" and add it to table and check.

Comment: now it is working....but it is checking all the radio buttons and checkbox and textbox...but my requirement is,we have validate whether one options is check or not...not the all options...

Comment: i think i completed that.....if you have any updates let me know...thanks for your helping...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102665/discussion-between-preet021991-and-fakkir-mohamed-sait).

Answer (score 0):

Radio button validation:
Html:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="21" name="radio" value="59"/>
    <input type="radio" id="22" name="radio" value="60"/>
    <input type="radio" id="23" name="radio" value="61"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
if ( ( form.radio[0].checked == false ) && ( form.radio[1].checked == false ) && ( form.radio[2].checked == false ) ) { alert ( "Please choose one radio button" ); return false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are many input box then use `each`..that will iterate just like for loop..

```js
  var iz_checked = false;
  var is_blank = false;
  var is_choose = false;
  $('button').on('click', function() {
iz_checked = false;
is_blank = false;
is_choose = false;
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
  if ($('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked') == true) {
    iz_checked = false;
  } else {
    iz_checked = true;
  }
  if ($('textarea')[0].value == "") {
    is_blank = true;
  }
});
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') == true) {
    is_choose = false;
  } else {
    is_choose = true;
  }
});
if (is_choose || iz_checked || is_blank) {
  alert("Validation err");
}

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <form>
  <input type="radio" id="21" value="59" />a
  <input type="radio" id="22" value="60" />q
  <input type="radio" id="23" value="61" />w
  <input type="radio" id="1" value="59" />e
  <input type="radio" id="2" value="60" />r
  <input type="radio" id="3" value="61" />t
  <input type="radio" id="29" value="59" />y
  <input type="radio" id="80" value="60" />u
  <input type="radio" id="7" value="61" />i
  <input type="radio" id="8" value="59" />o
  <input type="radio" id="0" value="60" />p
  <input type="radio" id="1" value="61" />l
</form>
<textarea cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Apples">f
<input type="checkbox" value="Apples">d
<input type="checkbox" value="Apples">s
<input type="checkbox" value="Apples">a
<br/>
<button>
  Validate
</button>
```

Comment: I am updating code with textarea and checkbox and correction in radio

Comment: Now updated with checkbox,textarea and radio button..if you ur requirement is different then let me know

Comment: i tried your's also...i have one doubt..$(document).ready function is needed before declaring the variable or not...already i have onclick() in that button...

Comment: you can put whole code in `$(document).ready`and if you have onclick() inline event then also you can write `.on('click',function(){}`